# How to get the decimal string representation of a decimal division?

Tags: c#, decimal, division

How can I have decimal part of a decimal division e,g.

```
decimal d = 10;
decimal result = d/10;
```

This gives `1`, how can I have `1.0` (still as a `decimal`, not `string`)?

Comment: you mean, you don't want the `decimal part` but the `decimal representation` of your data right?

Comment: you aren't using `d` in your division

Comment: They're the same numerical value. If it's a matter of presentation, you should use the appropriate methods like `.ToString ("#.##");`

Comment: That's a display issue, the value is `1` in both cases.  If you want that, use a proper `ToString()`.

Comment: 1 and 1.0 its the same in decimals...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The decimal value of `1` and `1.0` are equal. I'm assuming you want to see the format of the number with the decimal place.

To do that, you can use .NET [format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx). Personally, I generally use [custom format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx), so it would be:

```
string formattedDecimal = result.ToString("#,##0.0");
```

The `#` character means to put a digit there if one exists, but don't use leading zeroes. The `0` character means you're guaranteed to have a digit there, even if it's zero, so `1` will be formatted as `1.0`. If you don't want the grouping, you can leave out the hashes and comma and just have `ToString("0.0")`, which will give you the same thing, leaving out any potential thousands grouping.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a representation issue:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        decimal d = 10;
        decimal result = d / 10;

        Console.WriteLine( string.Format("{0:0.0}", result ) );
        // or
        Console.WriteLine( result.ToString("0.0") );
    }
}
```

They all print 1.0 as output.

<kbd>[`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/gyN3WU)</kbd>

Comment: Not sure what Ideone uses, but in the real .NET world, `Math.Round(result, 1)` still just returns the decimal value of `1m`, so writing that out will write `1`, not `1.0`.

Comment: @JoeEnos Damn, Ideone just fooled me :\ Thanks for the alert!